# Alter Maps javascript for auto entry

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have made several alterations to this script but I'm having no joy in changing it to auto load the map from a php variable I have.

The address I want the map to load is in the php variable `$address`

```
var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

I picked this code up from the maps documentation Google provide.

I want to change this so that when the initialize method loads, it automatically converts the `$address` variable into lat and long and displays it on the map. I have it doing it off the button to load codeAddress() at the moment but want it to become part of initialize!

Cheers!

Comment: Did you tried to put `codeAddress();` call at the bottom of `initialize()` function (just after `map = new google.maps.Map(...)`)?

Comment: That works but it means that hidden address input field has to remain. At the moment it's almost loaded two maps, a random one with the long and lat you see above and then the one I need. I want to cut the original one out and load it from the php variable!

Comment: You want to initialize map with `lat`/`lng` variables available in `php` code, right? Or you have only address string and want to retrieve coordinates in `php`?

Comment: The address is in the $address php variable and I need to enter that and convert to lat and long and then supply that to the map object to render correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this article: [**PHP server side geocoding** with **Google Maps API v3**](http://erlycoder.com/45/php-server-side-geocoding-with-google-maps-api-v3).

Simply find `lat`/`lng` pair on the server side (using `curl`)

```
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Some+Address";    

$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$contents = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

$resp = json_decode($contents, true);
$location = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']; // (Lat => x, Lng => y)
```

then render this in map initialization block

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$Lat;?>, <?=$Lng;?>);
```

Comment: I've tried this but I'm stuck on how to retrieve the lat and lng from the $location variable?

Comment: As with any other named array: `$location['lat']`, `$location['lng']`.

Comment: It doesn't return anything so I assumed it was something else!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/fedosov/266beba8be170c4bf0f3 this code prints `40.7143528-74.0059731`